# How to add security header parameters to SOAP Request in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soap-client, webservices-client

Default header is empty and I have to add security header to Soap request as below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:end="http://endpoint.soap.esb.steg.com.tn/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-633D8322A7C327A0D5153295320052614">
            <wsse:Username>website</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">7MyXmdbbBuyiHQwGCAY2+NxYRH8=</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">sdc+Kcgj/aghCxpUCACCxQ==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2018-07-30T12:20:00.526Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>    
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <end:consultInfoAboBT>
            <reference>00095013</reference>
        </end:consultInfoAboBT>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is my code

```
request = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:end='http://endpoint.soap.esb.steg.com.tn/'>"+ "<soapenv:Header/>"+"<soapenv:Body>" + "<end:consultInfoAboBT>"
+ "<reference>"+reference+"</reference>" + "</end:consultInfoAboBT>" + "</soapenv:Body>"+ "</soapenv:Envelope>";
StringEntity param = new StringEntity(request);     
response = json.makeHttpRequestSteg(URLSWSTEG1, "POST", param, message);
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response)));
```

Comment: What platform? what language?

Comment: @kiran Biradar I'm using java

Comment: This service is used by authenticating with a login / password pair to the web services server. In addition messages between the client (website) and the server are in HTTPS that is to say that the protection (encryption) messages is made by the transport layer in https.

Comment: Can you post how are you constructing and sending the soap message?

Comment: I add my code take a look @kiran Biradar

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer following example.

**HeaderHandlerResolver** header class :

```java
public class HeaderHandlerResolver implements HandlerResolver {
    @Override
    public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo portInfo) {
        List handlerChain = new ArrayList();
        HeaderHandler hh = new HeaderHandler();
        handlerChain.add(hh);
        return handlerChain;
    }    
}
```

**HeaderHandler** class :

```java
public class HeaderHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {

        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
            SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
            try {
                SOAPEnvelope envelope = smc.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
                SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
                if (header == null) {
                    header = envelope.addHeader();
                }
                SOAPElement security = header.addChildElement("Security", "wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");

                SOAPElement usernameToken = security.addChildElement("UsernameToken", "wsse");
                usernameToken.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:wsu"), "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
                usernameToken.addAttribute(QName.valueOf("wsu:Id"), "UsernameToken-1");
                SOAPElement username = usernameToken.addChildElement("Username", "wsse");
                username.addTextNode("username");
                SOAPElement password = usernameToken.addChildElement("Password", "wsse");
                password.setAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
                password.addTextNode("password");
                SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
                security.addAttribute(soapFactory.createName("SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand"), "1");
                message.saveChanges();
                message.writeTo(System.out);
                System.out.println("");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            try {

                SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
                message.writeTo(System.out);
                System.out.println("");

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return outboundProperty;
    }

    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return true;
    }

    public void close(MessageContext context) {
    }

}
```

Implement following under SOAP web service client method.

HeaderHandlerResolver handlerResolver = new HeaderHandlerResolver();
service.setHandlerResolver(handlerResolver);

Answer (score 0):

getHeader will return you complete header with usernametoken, You need to pass UserName,Password and created(date and time) in string format.

Like below

```
       request = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:end='http://endpoint.soap.esb.steg.com.tn/'>"

+ getHeader("website", "7MyXmdbbBuyiHQwGCAY2+NxYRH8=", "2018-07-30T12:20:00.526Z") +

    "<soapenv:Body>" + "<end:consultInfoAboBT>"
        + "<reference>"+reference+"</reference>" + "</end:consultInfoAboBT>" + "</soapenv:Body>"+ "</soapenv:Envelope>";
        StringEntity param = new StringEntity(request);     
        response = json.makeHttpRequestSteg(URLSWSTEG1, "POST", param, message);
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response)));
```

GetHeader() Function which will return Header token.

```
  public String getHeader(String Username, String Password, String Created)
    {
        String Nonce;
        String authID = "";
        String nonceLocal = "";
        Random randGen = new Random();

        nonceLocal = "" + randGen.nextInt();

        authID = nonceLocal  + Created + Password;

        MessageDigest mDigest = null;
        try {
            mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mDigest.reset();
        byte[] digestResult = mDigest.digest(authID.getBytes());

       Password = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(digestResult);
       Nonce = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(nonceLocal.getBytes());


        return "<soapenv:Header>\n" +
                "<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">\n" +
        "<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=\"UsernameToken-633D8322A7C327A0D5153295320052614\">\n" +
            "<wsse:Username> + Username + </wsse:Username>\n" +
            "<wsse:Password Type=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest\">" + Password + "</wsse:Password>\n" +
            "<wsse:Nonce EncodingType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary\">"+Nonce +"</wsse:Nonce>\n" +
            "<wsu:Created>" + Created +"</wsu:Created>\n" +
       "</wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>\n" +    
    "</soapenv:Header>";
    }
```